# Updating SVN property "svn:needs-lock"

Tags: svn

I want to update SVN property "svn:needs-lock" on all files in a directory structure   inside repository using svn command in Sun Solaris.

If I set it at trunk files, then while creating branch will it be carried to branch file ?
I have tried the below command and it gave me an error.

```
   svn propset -R svn:needs-lock yes http://<server>/BRANCH/001_SGPB/DIR
```

**ERROR**
       svn: Setting property on non-local target http:///BRANCH/001_SGPB/DIR' 
needs a base revision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to specify `--revprop` since you are running this command against the repository and not the working copy.  [See this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html)

Comment: could you update your link?  It references a version of Subversion that is over 5 years old.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.  I wish Google and the other search engines would pull the newer versions, but they don't.  What's even funnier is that one of the authors actually works for Google!